# 2 Pdo Selects are they working?

Tags: php, pdo

So I asked on here a few months ago for help I own a traffic exchange website users earn coins from viewing other users websites and gain coins. On my surf page I grab a random user were there coins are higher than 1 then grab one of there websites to use. Im just wondering if both my pdo selects are linked ?? That I am grabbing the username from the first select into the second one?

```
$stmt9 = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE coins >= ? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
$stmt9->execute( array('1') ) ;
$row = $stmt9->fetch();

$stmt212 = $db->prepare('SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  websites w
WHERE w.owner 
  IN (SELECT u.username FROM users u WHERE u.coins >= ?)  
ORDER BY 
  RAND() 
LIMIT 
  1');
$stmt212->execute( array($row['username']) ) ;
$row212 = $stmt212->fetch();
```

variables are messy i know.

Comment: are you shure with that: `where u.coins >= $row['username']` ???

Comment: You should not directly implement variables in the query.

Comment: @Alagaros yes, i know. I translated it because of a suspected logic bug. coins >= username makes no sense. it should be `$stmt212->execute( array('1') ) ;` and the second query works standalone.

Comment: So i just do a a select 1 row were coins > 1 then do another select for  select a website from there ??

Comment: The second select seems to be working only grabbing the websites with the coins left...